# How weatherproof is an average modern lens?

Tags: lens, weather, panasonic-lumix, weather-sealing

I recently bought the Panasonic GH4, which is weather-sealed. I also got the 14-140mm lens that Panasonic makes for it (I believe it's the first version and they have a new version -  mine is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028Y5GLO).

So I know I'm fine to use the GH4 out in some rain, or that kind of thing - I'm not sure exactly HOW much weather it'll take, but it'll obviously stand up to some - but I have no clue how it'd stand up to weather. Obviously it has electronics for the focusing/OIS/etc in it, and it doesn't specifically say it's weather protected, although someone mentioned in an Amazon review that they dropped it in snow and left it overnight and it was fine - but do I trust them??

The electronics are what scare me. I plan to use some of my older, fully manual lenses (or maybe some new Rokinon ones) and mostly use them in bad weather, which I think is ok (?), but does anyone know about newer lenses like the one mentioned?

Comment: What makes you think the Panasonic 14-140 is an "average modern lens" in terms of weatherproofing?

Comment: there's a good general discussion of weatherproofing in this [lensrentals.com blog](http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/12/assumptions-expectations-and-plastic-mounts) piece

Comment: @MichaelClark A better way to phrase the question might be: "How weatherproof are modern lenses like the Panasonic 14-140mm?"

Comment: Other question asks about cameras, but is nicely answered for lenses too.